# JavaScript: Is there an event like "restoring scroll position after refresh"? Is there any way to use/create it?

Tags: javascript, scroll

When you scroll a webpage, and refresh it, the scroll will jump to the place it was before the refresh. I have some scroll-related JavaScript, which modifies the visual state of the webpage on the "scroll" event, but it doesn't register the "scroll position restoring" after refresh. Currently I worked around it by simply setting `setTimeout`, waiting a while, and then reading the scroll position and running my code, but it isn't right. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to scroll after refresh its strange behave because when you refresh all website loading from scratch.
What can be done maybe to save it on localStorage the position and after the page loaded do scroll:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('position',window.pageYOffset);
}


    $(window).on('load', function(){

         window.scrollTo(0,localStorage.getItem('position')||0);
});
```

Comment: I'm very sorry if I stated this unclearly. I don't want to scroll, I want to run my own JS code which is dependent on the current scroll position. The problem is that after refresh, the scroll position is initially 0. Then it jumps to the position it was before refresh. Website is pretty JS heavy so this jump isn't instant, it takes fraction of the second to happen. Because the visuals of the website are scroll position dependent - I want to update them on this "jump" event, but I don't know how to catch it otherwise than waiting fixed amount of time, hoping it will happen in meantime.

Comment: if you want to listen to scroll event then : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp---> window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};      or second option window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {console.log('scrolling');});

Comment: This event doesn't trigger on this "scroll position restoring". It triggers only when I scroll manually, but not when the page jumps to the scroll position from before the refresh action.